# Does CQL3 support nested AND and OR

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

Given this sample table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
 pk1 text,
 pk2 text,
 pk3 text,
 pk4 text,
 data map<text, text>,
 PRIMARY KEY ((pk1, pk2, pk3), pk4)
);
```

I wonder if it is possible to have a query that selects different combinations of `pk2, pk3, pk4` with a fixed `pk1`. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE pk1 = 'abc' AND 
((pk2 = 'x' AND pk3 = 'y' AND pk4 = 'z') OR ((pk2 = 'd' AND pk3 = 'e' AND pk4 = 'f'));
```

I don't get this working. I have a set of `pk2, pk3, pk4` tuples and a fixed `pk1` and want to select all matching rows using a single query if possible (Cassandra 2.2.x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if it is possible to have a query that selects different combinations of pk2, pk3, pk4 with a fixed pk1.

No, it is not.

As Doan pointed out, `OR` is not supported (yet).  This leaves you with `AND` which makes nesting `WHERE` conditions superfluous.

Also, adding parens around your `AND` parts is not supported either.  Without parens this works, but not with them:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM row_historical_game_outcome_data
WHERE customer_id=123123 AND (game_id=673 AND game_time = '2015-07-01 05:01:42+0000');

SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:89 missing ')' at 'AND' (...=123123 AND (game_id=673 [AND] game_time...)">
```

That being said, the `IN` predicate will work on either the last partition or last clustering key.  But using it on a partition key is considered to be an anti-pattern.  In any case, in your case this would work (syntactically):

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE pk1 = 'abc' AND pk2 = 'x' AND pk3 = 'y' AND pk4 IN ('z','f');
```

Answer (score 2):

CQL supports **AND** predicate on columns

- that belong to the `PRIMARY KEY`
- that are indexed by the secondary index system

**OR** predicate is not supported. It will be supported as future enhancement of the new **[SASI secondary index](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/doc/SASI.md#limitations-and-caveats)**

Comment: Ok I guess that explains why there wasn't an `.or` method in the `QueryBuilder` of the datastax-driver :)